# How to prevent recreation of a list when a child property changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called `<Events events={Array} activeEventId={String} />`. `Events` component renders a list of `<Event event={Object} isActive={Bool} />` components, e.g.

```js
render () {
    let activeEventId,
        events;

    events = this.props.events;
    activeEventId = this.props.activeEventId;

    return <div>
        {events.map(function(event) {
            return <div key={event.id} >
                <Event event={event} isActive={event.id === activeEventId} />
            </div>;
        })}
        </div>;
}
```

Changing `activeEventId` recreates the entire list of `Event`s every time.

How to change the implementation that only the `Event` whose `isActive` prop has changed would get re-rendered?

Edit: Both `Events` and `Event` components are pure in that they only rely on their props, and don't use state at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `event` object and the `activeEventId` value to the `Event` component as props. Then you can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to check whether it should re-render or not.

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){
    //check if activeEventId changed
    return nextProps.activeEventId != this.props.activeEventId
}
```

Comment: I think the question refers to the parent component render, not the child.

Comment: @breno-ferreira That's what I am trying to do actually. Please refer to this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178260/how-to-prevent-recreation-of-a-list-when-a-child-property-changes#comment56103546_34178533

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's because the `Event` component doesn't have a `key` value. That causes React to recreate the component every time, assigning a different key value everytime the activeEventId changes. Try doing `<Event key={event.id} event={event} activeEventId={activeEventId} isActive={event.id === activeEventId} />`, remove the wrapping `div` and see if it works

Comment: @BrenoFerreira It still behaves the same way. `componentWillMount` gets called for each item in list but `shouldComponentUpdate` does not.

Comment: Can you provide a sample Fiddle that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the one of the React lifecycle method and it is `shouldComponentUpdate`

You have to check in shouldComponentUpdate that you have to call the render method of your component or not if you return false then it won't call your render method for more information use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html)

if you want to achieve it based on conditional then you have mark one flag which can hold the value of true and false and you can apply in your render method like

```
{isRender==true? <Event event={event} isActive={event.id === activeEventId} />:null}
```

Comment: @GajusKuizinas: Good question but OP didn't mentioned in question whether it's a state or stateless component

Comment: That's the problem. `shouldComponentUpdate` would get called only while updating the component, not when it's created for first time. For some reason, `Event` components get re-created every time prop of `Events` component change. I can confirm this because `shouldComponentUpdate` on `Event` component never gets called, but `componentWillMount` gets called instead (which should get called only on first mount of the component).

Comment: so what you can apply logic  in componentwillMount method it will call everytime before render called or you can also use componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I don't want to execute any special logic, I want to avoid calling `render` on every unchanged `Event` component, which I believe can only be done by calling `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` should be called before each re-render unless the key has changed or the type has changed. In the code you've posted, you're correctly using keys as far as I can tell, and you're obviously always rendering Event components, so there's no reason why your Event components unmount and remount. Are the event ids correctly set?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take here:

1) Implement `shouldComponentUpdate` on the Event component. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rryy4knv/) with your example using a rudimentary `shouldComponentUpdate` method. In the log, you can see that only 2 Events get re-rendered (the one that became active and the one that is no longer active). If the `Event` components are getting destroyed in your code, you're probably not generating your keys correctly, make sure they stay consistent between renders.

2) Assuming you're using some variant of Flux, you could have your `Event` components listen on a store and keep the `isActive` flag within their state, updating it when the store triggers the corresponding change. This is a bit more efficient, since it does not repeatedly call `EventList.render` or even `Event.shouldComponentUpdate`. Only the Events that actually change respond to the change by updating their state and re-rendering. This introduces more complexity however, since it forces you to put state in child components, which is always something you'd like to avoid. I'd definitely try to go with 1) unless you really need to optimize every bit.